# Yoxview make crash IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7

I have a photo/video gallery and I apply the Yoxview jquery plugin on. On every browser their is no problem except for IE7.

I try to update my code to the latest version of the plugin but it does not helped.

The strange part is that I go on the Yoxview site, IE7 doest not crash.

This is the code is use:

```
$(".Gallery").yoxview();
```

.Gallery is a `div` with nested `a` that contains `img`.

Do anybody have encounter this situation before me?

**NOTE**: The problem exist even if their is only 1 image on the page.

Comment: try changing .Gallery to an id? Chances are its something else on your site or what you are trying to render.

Comment: What exactly happens?  You say that the browser "crashes"; is that really correct?  The whole browser process dies?

Comment: @Pointy Yes the whole process crashes and I have to restart my browser.

Comment: Passing by the ID of the object make the browser tell me that a script take time to run and I want to kill this script.

Comment: I created a test page outside of my web project (no desing) with a small list of picture and it work well in IE7. So I suppose that a Javascript include that cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

I change my Jquery version. The version 1.6 seam to cause the problem. I try with the 1.4 and the plugin work perfectly. So, I got to the Jquery site and download the latest version of Jquery (1.6.1) and everything is now ok.

Thank for you help guys!